# Does the damage bonus from Two-Handed-Style apply to spells?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I just got to choose my first talent and noticed that the Two-Handed-Style talent provides quite a substantial damage bonus. As I'm wielding a staff as a wizard right now, this looks quite handy if it actually applies to my spells as well as my staff damage.

The description doesn't seem entirely clear to me, it doesn't actually restrict the damage bonus to anything. Does the bonus apply to *any* damage my character does, or are there restrictions that aren't explicitly listed here?

[image]

Comment: I don't *think* so; should be easy enough to check with a saved game at a level up. I'll try to remember to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to affect anything but melee damage, after some quick testing on a Cipher at level up with a poleaxe.

Answer (score 0):

weapons do not affect the accuracy or damage of spells.  they are completely independent of one another.  As for the two-handed buff, it doesn't seem to apply, at least with the latest patch 1.04, to all two-handed weapons even.  ranged weapons for instance seem not to apply, after a bit of testing.  quite an oversight if you ask me